# Acessando dados de uma array Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic

Estou tentando acessar um o dado de ID que minha `API` responde que está dentro de um array:

```
{
  "name": <name>
  "email": <email>
  "token": <token>
  "message": 'Token válido.'
  "subscriptions": [
   {
     "id": "<id>", // preciso pegar a id
     "startdate": "<startdate>",
     "enddate": "<enddate>",
     "active": "<active>",
     "course": "<course>"
   }]
}
```

Estou guardando no `localStorage` do celular da seguinte forma:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authloginService.getCourses(this.token, this.course)
    .then((result)=> {         
      localStorage.setItem('subscriptions(id)', result['subscriptions'])
      console.log(result['subscriptions']);      
     });
  }
```

Porém o `console.log` me responde a array inteira de `subscriptions`;

Aqui o service:

```
getCourses(token:string, course:string){    
    token = encodeURIComponent (localStorage.getItem('token'));
    course = encodeURIComponent (course);     
    var cursos = `token=${token}&course=${course}`;    
    return this.http.post('https://minhaapi.com.br/api/subscriptions', 
              cursos , {headers: this.headers}).toPromise();

}
```

Estou errando no `localStorage` ou no serviço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que está errando na hora do armazenamento:

Pode ser feito assim:

```
localStorage.setItem('subscriptions(id)', result['subscriptions'][0]['id']);
```

onde nesse caso é armazenado `id` do retorno no `localStorage` e para recuperar o valor novamente:

```
const id = localStorage.getItem('subscriptions(id)');
```

é a mais simples solução.

Ou poderia ser feito assim guardar todo o resultado utilizando o `JSON` em texto com [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
localStorage.setItem('subscriptions(id)', JSON.stringify(result));
```

e depois na sua recuperação da `id` pegando o texto gerado e transformando `JSON` com o comando [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
const json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('subscriptions(id)'));
```

e depois utilizar dessa forma para também recuperar o `id` (vale lembrar que pode recuperar todos os valores, estou sendo especifico a pergunta)

```
const id = json.subscriptions[0].id;
```

```js
const json = {
  "name": "<name>",
  "email": "<email>",
  "token": "<token>",
  "message": "Token válido.",
  "subscriptions": [
     {
        "id": "1", 
        "startdate": "<startdate>",
        "enddate": "<enddate>",
        "active": "<active>",
        "course": "<course>"
      }
   ]
};

console.log(json.subscriptions[0].id); // ou
console.log(json['subscriptions'][0]['id']);
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado !